# Getting started with FingerText and Notepad++: Hot-spots disappearing

Tags: notepad++

I've been using TextPad for 15 years or so, and I'm daring to give Notepad++ a try. After reading this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737503/2736496

and watching his cool video, I'm also giving FingerText a try.

I have the following snippet, which contains four hot-spots, the first and third of which share the same output-text.

```
  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
   CIObject.nullOrReturnCause($[![var-name]!], $[![(lis)s_clgFunc|YYY|"YYY"]!], "$[![var-name]!]", $[![(lis)null|o_xtraInfo]!], rtx);
}$[0[]0][>END<]
```

It is working just fine, up until I get to the second hotspot: `$[![(lis)s_clgFunc|YYY|"YYY"]!]`. While it presents the three options in a drop-down, as expected, and it prints my selection correctly, it is causing the next two hotspots to disappear.

After typing `o_theObject` into the first hotspot--which is duplicated into the third--this is the result:

```
  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
   CIObject.nullOrReturnCause(o_theObject, $[![(lis)s_clgFunc|YYY|"YYY"]!], "o_theObject", $[![(lis)null|o_xtraInfo]!], rtx);
}$[0[]0]
```

Good so far. Now hotspot two, `$[![(lis)s_clgFunc|YYY|"YYY"]!]`, is highlighted, and I choose `"YYY"` from its drop-down. It results in this:

```
  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
CIObject.nullOrReturnCause(o_theObject, "YYY", rtx);
}$[0[]0]
```

This is unexpected. The third hotspot (the duplicate of the first) has disappeared, as has the fourth: `$[![(lis)null|o_xtraInfo]!]`.

What am I missing here? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I use nothing but vim now. I love it. Hopefully you get an answer from erinata. Good luck!

Comment: Shame. Really great software that has apparently been left to rot. Still no response from erinata. She (she?) hasn't responded to anything on GitHub for at least a couple months  :(